# How to change column values in dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I am trying to modify the values in a dataframe[column]. I am using slugify to change the values in column.

```
df[column][0] = "Hello-World"
df[column][1] = "Hi There!"

df[column] type is series
```

Expected value after slugify

```
df[column][0] = "hello-world"
df[column][1] = "hi_there"
```

I tried couple of iterations but cannot get it to work correctly

```
  df[column_name] = slugify.slugify(str(df[column_name]))
```

The above resulted in concatenation of all values into a long string and being assigned to each row in the column.

I also tried the following but the got the same result as above.

```
df[column_name] = slugify.slugify((df[column_name].to_string(index=False,header=False)))
```

Any suggestions how can i apply slugify on each value in the column.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just directly [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the `slugify` function

```
df.column1.apply(slugify.slugify)
```

which in your case yields

```
0    hello-world
1       hi-there
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

---

Your original attempt of

```
 slugify.slugify(str(df[column_name]))
```

evidently won't work, because `str(df[column_name])` yields a string representation for the entire column, which is then slugified.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
from slugify import slugify
df['column_name'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x :slugify(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a better answer.
It's better because there's no external library required.

```
df['col'] = df.col.replace(' ','-',regex=True)
```

**regex=True** is the trick

Comment: Simple ... Like this approach